# VS Code is not running Python Programs and is showing a Powershell Advert on the Terminal and the Terminal is not showing the path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: Problem]

As soon as I click 'Run Python File in Terminal', it does nothing, no errors, nothing just remains idle, but if I run the same file with the python IDLE, it works, I re-installed the latest version of Python and VS Code but still the problem isn't solved.
Also, the Terminal shows a Powershell advert and doesn't show the path like it usually should.

Edit: Powershell shows an advert and doesn't work properly

[image: Powershell]

The code runs properly in CMD

[image: CMD]

The VS Code extensions I use are:

1. Bracket Pair Colorizer
2. Code Runner
3. Jupyter (Idk what it does but VS Code prompted me to install it for Python)
4. Live Server
5. Material Icon Theme
6. Pylance (Idk what it does but VS Code prompted me to install it for Python)
7. Python

This is the content of settings.json

```
{
    "editor.fontSize": 18,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "window.zoomLevel": -1,
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": [],
    "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
    "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.saveAllFilesBeforeRun": true,
    "code-runner.saveFileBeforeRun": true
}
```

Because of this problem, I ignored VS Code and installed PyCharm and I am having no issues with it.

Comment: What happens when you click on the green run symbol on the top right corner?

Comment: @Shivansh Sahu -Could you run this code in a cmd terminal outside of VS Code?
Could you please provide us with which VS Code extensions you have used and the content of the settings file "settings.json"?

Comment: @JillCheng Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the information you provided, the problem is that the powershell terminal that comes with the system cannot be used. Because VS Code is an editor, its internal powershell terminal integrates the powershell terminal from the system. However, VS Code not only supports this terminal, it also supports cmd terminal, bash and so on.

Solution: Since you can run python code in cmd terminal outside of VS Code, please use

```
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
```

instead of

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
```

in "settings.json" in VS Code to switch the terminal to cmd.

Or you could use the following method, which can also switch the terminal to cmd:

[image]

Reference:  [Integrated terminal in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_windows).